# Sudden problems with Spyder and Jupyter kernels

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter, spyder

I have loaded Jupyter this morning (Paris, Berlin timezone) and it could not connect with the kernel.

I then tried to open Spyder, and I get the following error:

[image]

I looked online what it could be the case, but I have no background on this kind of "advanced" configuration.

Is it something related to any newly released update?

I don´t recall modifying anything since yesterday, when it was working with flying colours.

This is the error that prompts on Jupyter:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Hope this post helps others too.

Best regards,
Enrique

Comment: Dear Community: by reinstalling Anaconda, I have been able to get Spyder working again. Seems like Jupyter is still not accessing the kernel. I would be very grateful for some help on with this mater. Thanks

Comment: This problem will be fixed in our **4.1.1** version, which should be released today or tomorrow at most.